# Perform energy minimization of multiple models of protein-dna complexes

Tags: software-recommendations, gromacs, proteins, atomistic-simulation, chimera-software

Is there a software/standalone tool that can perform energy minimization of a large number of protein-dna complex models (more than 1000)?

I know of GROMACS or Chimera or the online servers but is there a downloadable tool which I can use to minimize all the complexes and say for example, include in my script for further processing of said models?

Comment: If you only wants to do geometry optimization, OpenBabel can do that using different force fields.

Answer (score 1):

[Camps wrote](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/perform-energy-minimization-of-multiple-models-of-protein-dna-complexes#comment20535_9754):

> "If you only want to do geometry optimization, OpenBabel can do that using different force fields."

This Community Wiki answer can be deleted if someone wants to write a more detailed answer.